# Sort <String,Double> HashMap using comparator and without TreeMap

Tags: java, string, hashmap, comparator

Trying to sort HashMap of <String,Double> without using treeMap or other method. Need the code to pass a hashMap and return a sorted hashMap in the fastest time.  What am I doing wrong with the string Comparator.  Please look and advise.  Thank you very much!!!

```
/// Here's the main
package Sort_String_Double_without_TreeMap;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Map<String, Double> outGoing = new HashMap<>();

        outGoing.put("J", -5.0);
        outGoing.put("X", 0.7);
        outGoing.put("C", 0.0);
        outGoing.put("D", 80.0);
        outGoing.put("A", 80.0);
        
        
        System.out.println("---UNSORTED---");

        System.out.println(outGoing);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
    

        Helper_SorterClass sorter = new Helper_SorterClass ();

        System.out.println("---SORTED---");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("SIZE= " + sorter.SortHashMapKey(outGoing).size());
        
        System.out.println(sorter.SortHashMapKey(outGoing));

    }

    
    
}
```

And Here's the other class...

```
/// Here's the helper class

package Sort_String_Double_without_TreeMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class Helper_SorterClass {


public Map<String, Double> SortHashMapKey(Map<String, Double> unsortedMap) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList(unsortedMap.keySet());
        
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                
                return String.valueOf(o1).compareTo(String.valueOf(o2));
                
            }
        });

        Map<String, Double> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (String keys : list) {
            sortedMap.put(keys, unsortedMap.get(keys));
            }
        return sortedMap;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately getting wrong output.

```
run:
---UNSORTED---
{A=80.0, C=0.0, D=80.0, X=0.7, J=-5.0}
---SORTED---

SIZE= 5
{A=80.0, C=0.0, D=80.0, X=0.7, J=-5.0}
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    Map<String, Double> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (String keys : list) {
         sortedMap.put(keys, unsortedMap.get(keys));
    }
```

you should use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap as below:

```
    Map<String, Double> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String keys : list) {
         sortedMap.put(keys, unsortedMap.get(keys));
    }
```

HashMap doesn't maintain insertion order. So once you put the entries in a new HashMap() after comparing, it will again give unsorted result when you iterate over the new map. But if you use a LinkedHashMap, it will maintain insertion order while iterating.